# Spawn a user profile chooser on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to spawn a profile chooser on Windows like the one that appears when selecting the profile for a service in services.msc this in order to get the domain and the username.

For example:

[image: Example of profile chooser]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directory Object Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)